# How to support optional localisation strings in routes with React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react-router I need to allow the internationalisation of links; so this is an outline;

```
domain.com/langISO/countryISO2/page
```

these would all be valid routes as an example;

```
domain.com/ -> Home Page
domain.com/en/us -> Home Page
domain.com/fr/fr -> Home Page
domain.com/en/gb/settings -> Settings Page
domain.com/en/gb/account -> Account Page
domain.com/settings -> Settings Page
domain.com/es/us -> Homepage (with spanish and united states localisation)
```

So its like

The langISo or CountryISO will always be in a pair of two character strings and will be a valid country ISO (it does not need to know if the countryISO is correct or not, just that it meets the syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be;

```
<Route path={['/:a([a-zA-Z]{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{2})/about', '/about']} component={AboutPage} />
```

Requires both locales, or none.